# Visual Studio Code venv support

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I'm using Python's `venv` and am unsure how to get VS Code to recognise the folder layout.

The interpreter is the system-level Python, so it doesn't see the project's `Lib/`, `Scripts/`, `Include/`, etc. and thus fails to find (import) the modules I've already added.

Is there a way to configure VS Code to work with `venv` projects and non-`venv` ones, or do I have to set `python.pythonPath` per-project?

Answer (score 1):

Open a folder in the level above your venv directory.  Then VS Code will discover the python.exe that lives inside /Scripts.

For example, if you created your venv in C:\MyProjects

```
C:\MyProjects> python -m venv MyEnv
```

Then in VS Code,

```
Open Folder... (Ctrl-K Ctrl-O)
```

Select C:\MyProjects

```
Command Palette... (Ctrl-Shift-P)
Python: Select Interpreter<Enter>
```

You should now see a dropdown list that includes .\MyEnv\Scripts\python.exe.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2470#issuecomment-418459133